# Farming Ascension Items

Tags: fate-grand-order

I'm missing stuff like Proof of Heroes, Dragon Fangs, Void Refuse, etc... and I thought I'd be able to get them from the Monster Hunting daily quests in Chaldea gate. However, all I get are the gems required for Skill enhancements.

How do I efficiently farm for these Ascension items?

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient way is to participate events launched every month and farm the vent material to be exchanged to your desired Ascension material.

The drop rates for these items are low (FGO has very bad drop rates) and it will take time and dedication to get these items by farming.